# Get volume id from newly created ebs volume using ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, orchestration, ansible

I used ansible's ec2_vol module to create an ebs volume. I saw the source code and found that it internally calls create_volume() method of boto with user specified parameters. I want to register the return value of ec2_vol module and get the volume_ids of newly created volumes.

As of now my playbook looks like

```
- name: Attach a volume to previously created instances
  local_action: ec2_vol instance={{item.id}} volume_size=5 aws_access_key={{aa_key}} aws_secret_key={{as_key}} region={{region}}
  with_items: ec2.instances
  register: ec2_volumes
  ignore_errors: yes

- name: Stop the instances
  local_action: command aws ec2 stop-instances --profile=xervmon --instance-id={{item.id}}
  with_items: ec2.instances
  ignore_errors: yes

- name: Detach volume from instances
  local_action: command aws ec2 detach-volume --profile=xervmon --volume-id=????                                                
  ignore_errors: yes
```

I would like to know how to get the volume ids of newly created volumes. I saw that run_instances() method's return object has an attribute instances whcih contain a list of instances. But I couldn't find any proper documentation of create_volume() method's return value.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [ec2_vol module source code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/library/cloud/ec2_vol#L271-L274), the module returns:

- `volume_id`
- `device`

In your case, you are creating multiple volumes via with_items, so the `ec2_volumes` variable that you register will be a dictionary with a key named `results` that holds the list of results from each of the individual ec2_vol invocations.

Here's an example that prints out the volume ids (warning: I haven't tested this).

```
- name: Attach a volume to previously created instances
  local_action: ec2_vol instance={{item.id}} volume_size=5 aws_access_key={{aa_key}} aws_secret_key={{as_key}} region={{region}}
  with_items: ec2.instances
  register: ec2_volumes

- name: Print out the volume ids
  debug: msg={{ item.volume_id }}
  with_items: ec2_volumes.results
```

Comment: Yeah it worked...Thanks a lot..But how did you figure out that the key name used in ec2_volumes's dictionary is 'results' and not something else... I looked for some documentation but wasn't able to find it...

Comment: @Pattu I found out by doing something similar to above, using debug to dump the contents of the variable. I've submitted a pull request to improve the documentation on this: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/4099

Comment: @Pattu If this answers your question, can you please accept the provided answer?

Comment: I saw the github pull request..It might sound silly but I didn't understand what you meant by accepting the answer....

Comment: When I use the above playbook...i get the following error. "fatal: [localhost] => One or more undefined variables: 'str object' has no attribute 'volume_id'"

Comment: what if volume_size, region, etc.. is stored in a dictionary variable. How can you have multiple with items / dicts?

Comment: got it, used with_nested