# Getting just volume id ansible

Tags: parsing, ansible

This has been answered before here on Stack.

[ansible get aws ebs volume id which already exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41659564/ansible-get-aws-ebs-volume-id-which-already-exist)

[Get volume id from newly created ebs volume using ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853891/get-volume-id-from-newly-created-ebs-volume-using-ansible)

For the life of me I am trying ec2_vol.volume_id and some other jmespath query bits but not getting the right output help. I just want the vol id. Nothing more.

```
---
 - hosts: localhost
   connection: local
   gather_facts: no
   tasks:
   - name: get associated vols
     ec2_vol:
       instance: i-xxxxxxxxxxxxx
       state: list
       profile: default
       region: us-east-1
     register: ec2_vol

   - debug:
       msg: "{{ ec2_vol.volume_id }}"
```

also doesn't work

```
---
 - hosts: localhost
   connection: local
   gather_facts: no
   tasks:
   - name: get associated vols
     ec2_vol:
       instance: i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
       state: list
       profile: default
       region: us-east-1
     register: ec2_vol

   - debug: msg="{{ item.volume_id }}"
     with_items: ec2_vol.results
```

Ansible 2.2 and 2.3 tested

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ansible get aws ebs volume id which already exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41659564/ansible-get-aws-ebs-volume-id-which-already-exist) -- as you noticed: it has been answered -- apply the solution from the answer instead of repeating the code from the question.

Comment: There was no copying of code from the question. However in the prior answers there is use of `volume_id` which doesn't work. Then there is the capability to pass in items to the debug message. Which also doesn't work for me.

Comment: The aforementioned possible answer above doesn't assist. There are far more elegant measures to get the volume. That answer starts msg from ec2 not ec2_vol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking bits from the prior answer you will need to understand JMESPATH like filtering to get what you want out of the output.

Here is the answer

```
---
 - hosts: localhost
   connection: local
   gather_facts: no
   tasks:
   - name: get associated vols
     ec2_vol:
       instance: i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
       state: list
       profile: default
       region: us-east-1
     register: ec2_vol

   - debug: msg="{{ ec2_vol.volumes | map(attribute='id') | list }}"
```